# How to call the VueJs object via Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, vuex

How to call the VueJs object via Chrome Extension?

I'm using the chrome.tabs.executeScript function to try to execute the code inside the active tab.

The idea is to change the values ​​of the fields.

So far I am unsuccessful.

Could anyone help?

My app Main

```
window.App = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Chrome Extension

```
chrome.tabs.query({url:"http://localhost:8081/portaria/create"}, function(tabs) {

                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {content: true, body:response.documento}, function(response){

                            chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[0].id, {code:"console.log(App)"});
                            chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[0].id, {code:"console.log(window.App)"});
                            chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[0].id, {code:"window.App.$store.state.form.nfe.codigo = 102"});

                        });
                    });
```

[image]

**** UPDATE *****

Manifest

```
{
    "name": "Nfe - Nutrane",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Nfe"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "app.js"
      ]
}
```

Content

```
 var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('app.js');
  (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
  s.onload = function() {
      s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
  };
console.log(App)
```

[image]

Comment: Your injected code should dive a level deeper, in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: I think I have part of it. Do I have to load the builded file into the extension folder?

Thank you friend.

Comment: Yes, you can either use a separate js script or use a string. The answer I've linked contains all examples.

Comment: I tried to use method 1 but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Add the new code and how you call it to the question.

Comment: https://ibb.co/vdvLPsnhttps://ibb.co/xgLy9Zq

Comment: Add the new code and how you call it to the question. Otherwise I can't help.

Comment: Done. Edited...

Comment: I don't see app.js. It should be a script file in your extension. That script will be able to see window.App. Not your content script. Your content script can't see `App` so console.log should be inside app.js. Your entire app.js will be literally `console.log(App)`.

Comment: Excuse. More I can not understand. Could you exemplify?

I still can't get the extension to read the Vuejs App.

I am tired, but I intend to continue to learn more about this. thak you

Comment: What I still don't understand is what it should contain inside script.js?

Comment: script.js is `console.log(App)`

Comment: script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at script.js:1

Comment: Your content script is running at `document_start` before the page initialized so this is the correct behavior. Either remove `run_at` or use an event like DOMContentLoaded or `load`.

Comment: Something strange has happened. App is not defined, however in the list window the App object is there

Comment: I have no idea what `list window` is.

Comment: https://ibb.co/b1q3RgR

Comment: where to change to include DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Devtools evaluates the objects in console when you expand them, not when they were logged, so there's nothing strange.

Comment: As for DOMContentLoaded, it's a basic feature of DOM so there should be lots of examples. There's not a lot of places where you can use it so if it's unclear just try them all. It also depends on when your App initializes, maybe it does so at a later point in time.

Comment: Okay, I will search on. One last question. How to access the App object inside content.js or vice versa

Comment: Content script can't access the App object.

Comment: To avoid going in circles, I've edited [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) I've linked in the beginning to clarify some points so now it should be more obvious.

Comment: So I won't be able to do what I need to do.

I need the content to perform the function contained in the App

Comment: It's possible. As explained and shown in that answer you need to separate the code that accesses the page object from the content script. Then use communication between the two parts. I think this is all obviously explained in the answer I've linked after my edits...