# How to update the Vue form field through the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to update the Vue form field through the DOM?

I need to update field data through an external script. For this I need to know if it is possible to update the data through the DOM.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-feistel-26r4v?file=/src/store.js

I tried to do it directly through the Store, but in my case it doesn't work.

[How to call the VueJs object via Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841913/how-to-call-the-vuejs-object-via-chrome-extension)

Example

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName('el-input__inner')[0].value = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ref` for similar to querySelector reference in SFC.

in `<template>`:

```html
<input type="text" ref="thisRef" name="textfield_1"/>
```

in `<script>` methods call:

```js
this.$refs.thisRef[0].value = 10
```

Other than that, there's `v-model` for data binding.

hope helps